# Sequelize migration is being applied however there is no change to the database

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a simple migration that renames a column. The migration file looks like this:

```
const tableName= 'aTable';

module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        queryInterface.renameColumn(tableName, 'oldName', 'newName');
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        queryInterface.renameColumn(tableName, 'newName', 'oldName');
    },
};
```

When I apply the migration, I get the following output:

```
== migrateFile: migrating =======
== migrateFile: migrated (0.071s)
```

Then when I use the model, I get the following error:

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: column aTable.newName does not exist
```

If I print out the columns, I see the oldName is still in the table. Other migrations seem to work.

The database is postgres. I'm starting to take a look at the logs to see if I can find anything.

Is there any way I can debug sequelize to figure out what is going on? Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Is it possible you applied it on one db, then verified (used the model) on another? You might want to check your [environment variables](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#security-tip), [config](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#configuration) and [.sequelizerc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#the-sequelizerc-file)

Comment: I was thinking of something like that but I'm using the --url flag with the servername, port and database name included. I don't have any other configuration files. I did find there's a way to set the logging for the renameColumn function, so I'm going to try that next.

Comment: i turned on the logging by adding the option logging: console.log and it printed out ALTER TABLE "aTable" RENAME COLUMN "oldName" TO "newName"; and the column updated correctly. I'm not sure what changed (besides adding the logging), but I'll try again to see if I can recreate and get some other output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to wait for the result of renaming query, just add `await` and that's it:

```js
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.renameColumn(tableName, 'oldName', 'newName');
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.renameColumn(tableName, 'newName', 'oldName');
    },
};
```

Comment: This sounds like the correct answer. My only question is why does the log say 
== migrateFile: migrating =======
== migrateFile: migrated (0.071s)

Wouldn't that imply that the migration went through?

Comment: It just says the migration itself completed but if you started some async stuff inside it and you don't wait for it then the migration will done almost immediately and all such changes most likely will be dropped. To check this case open explicit transaction and pass to `renameColumn` and don't add `await` before `renameColumn` (but before transaction indeed).

Comment: Another reason why I selected this answer, I checked all of the other migrations in my code base and they all have the await.